how to query for nearest neighbour in opensearch?
I'm running a query against an aws open search instance. I added a sample index, with few fields including a vector field, i want to do a k nearest neighbour search. I ran a sample query and got back few results. is there a way to get back the distance between the query vector and result vector .
also,  in the result i get back a score field ('_score': 0.0453) , what does this score mean? could someone point me to the docs ?
PUT my-index
{
   "settings":{
     "index.knn": true
   },
   "mappings":{
     "properties":{
        "my_vector":{
           "type"      : "knn_vector", 
           "dimension" : 1024
        }
     }
   }
}

search query -
data={
  "query":{
     "knn":{
            "vector": [93, 39, 46, 487...],
            "k": 2
     }                 
  }
}

search results
{
  'took': 1, 
  'timed_out': False,
  '_shards': {'total':5, 'successful': 5....},
  'hits':{
     'total': { 'value':2 },
     'max_score': 0.0453,
     'hits':[
        { 
           '_index' : 'my_index',
           '_score': 0.0453, 
           '_source': {
               ....
           }
        }
     ]
  }
}

